# Return regular expression only one time

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I am trying to have regular expression only print the result one time. Is there any suggestions? Since I want the code to read the entire text file, but there are many dates that are the same, but I just want the code to return that date one time only.

code:

```
import re
filename = set(open('wireshark.txt', 'r'))

pattern_object = re.compile(r'(\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d)')
for line in filename:
        match_object = pattern_object.search(line)
        if match_object:
                regex = match_object.group(1)
                print(regex)
```

Text file:

```
No.     Time                          Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      2 2021-02-12 13:33:12.206424    192.168.1.151         172.217.10.46         QUIC     1392   Initial, DCID=e4267bae554f387d, PKN: 1, CRYPTO, PADDING

Frame 2: 1392 bytes on wire (11136 bits), 1392 bytes captured (11136 bits) on interface \Device\NPF_{28AA034F-AC94-4D4A-9CA9-9AEA5D0EF2C1}, id 0
Ethernet II, Src: Micro-St_0e:cd:34 (00:d8:61:0e:cd:34), Dst: Verizon_fb:8b:82 (20:c0:47:fb:8b:82)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.1.151, Dst: 172.217.10.46
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 57189, Dst Port: 443
QUIC IETF

No.     Time                          Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      3 2021-02-12 13:33:12.225610    172.217.10.46         192.168.1.151         QUIC     1392   Initial, SCID=e4267bae554f387d, PKN: 1, ACK, CRYPTO, PADDING

Frame 3: 1392 bytes on wire (11136 bits), 1392 bytes captured (11136 bits) on interface \Device\NPF_{28AA034F-AC94-4D4A-9CA9-9AEA5D0EF2C1}, id 0
Ethernet II, Src: Verizon_fb:8b:82 (20:c0:47:fb:8b:82), Dst: Micro-St_0e:cd:34 (00:d8:61:0e:cd:34)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 172.217.10.46, Dst: 192.168.1.151
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 443, Dst Port: 57189
QUIC IETF

No.     Time                          Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      4 2021-02-12 13:33:12.225989    192.168.1.151         172.217.10.46         TLSv1.2  146    Application Data
No.     Time                          Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      4 2021-04-12 13:33:12.225989    192.168.1.151         172.217.10.46         TLSv1.2  146    Application Data
No.     Time                          Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      4 2021-06-12 13:33:12.225989    192.168.1.151         172.217.10.46         TLSv1.2  146    Application Data
No.     Time                          Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      4 2021-06-12 13:33:12.225989    192.168.1.151         172.217.10.46         TLSv1.2  146    Application Data
```

Code execute output:

```
2021-02-12
2021-02-12
2021-02-12
2021-02-12
2021-02-12
2021-02-12
2021-04-12
2021-06-12
2021-06-12
```

desire code execute output:

```
2021-02-12
2021-04-12
2021-06-12
```

Comment: break? I am new with python I don't know what you mean by break

Answer (score 1):

Here's a minimal example for how to get all the unique dates in the file.

Essentially, it's a 4 stage process:

1. Store the pattern to search for as a string
2. Open the file and get all the text
3. Use `re.findall()` to get all of the text matching the pattern
4. Use `set()` to keep only the unique matches

```py
import re

# Make the pattern
pattern = '(\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d)'

# Open the file and read all the text into a variable
with open('wireshark.txt') as file:
  text = file.read()
  
# Search the text for anything matching the pattern
matches = re.findall(pattern, text)

# Print the unique matches
print(set(matches))
```

The key thing here is the combination of `re.findall()` (search for multiple matches at once) and `set()` (to get rid of duplicates.

Comment: I didn't know about that, but this could be useful for me. However, I meant for the regular expression to run through the whole text file because there are different dates in the file, but I don't want the same date to be printed over and over alone with those different dates as well. I edited the question so you can see what I mean

Comment: @duynguyen I've edited my answer now - I think that's more what you're looking for.